# What is the meaning of "this" in a Processing statement parameter

Tags: class, oop, this

In the Processing language, to use a serial port an object of the class `serial` is needed, typically created by the statement:

`myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[4], 4800);`

I am puzzled by the `this` argument, and the best reference I can find is [here](http://www.technotype.net/processing/reference/libraries/serial/Serial.html) which has the following entry.

```
Constructor 
    Serial(parent)
    Serial(parent, rate)
    Serial(parent, name)
    Serial(parent, name, rate)
    Serial(parent, name, rate, parity, databits, stopbits)
Parameters  
    parent  PApplet: typically use "this"
```

I have tried to find out the meaning of the description of the`parent` parameter. I understand, I think, that it refers to the object that the `myport` is part of, but then get lost in a jungle of technicalities. So now I need to know: what is a Papplet, and how does this relate Processing to Java (and indeed C++)? Please can someone explain it simply for me, or give me a reference to where it is nicely described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice answer to this in chapter 23 of "Learning Processing" by Daniel Shiffman, published by Morgan Kaufmann, ISBN 978-0-12-373602-4. As I now understnd it a Processing sketch is wrapped in code that turns it into a `public class JavaExample extends PApplet {...}`, and is then compiled  into a Java program and run. So the `this` parameter refers to the parental wrapped round class.

The similarity to C++ is explained in [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)), which says "The (Java) language derives much of its syntax from C and C++, but it has fewer low-level facilities than either of them."